# Explain how works the AWK script

Tags: awk

Can anyone explain how it works:

```
$ cat dup.awk
{   fields[$COL]++
    if (fields[$COL] == 1) {
        cache[$COL] = $0
    } else {
        if (fields[$COL] == 2) {print cache[$COL]}
        print $0
    }
}

$ awk -f dup.awk -vCOL=2 ./file
```

I know what this does, but **HOW** I cannot understand.

Especially interested in this:`foo[$BAR]++`

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` operates on one record (line) at a time with rules. You have 1 rule and you are passing 1 variable from the command line `-vCOL=2`.

Your script uses the array `fields` as a counter for the number of times each unique 2nd field occurs.

```
fields[$COL]++
```

It then checks if that was the first time the value for the 2nd field was seen.

```
if (fields[$COL] == 1)
```

If it was the first occurrence of the 2nd field it stores the entire record `$0` in the array `cache` indexed by the 2nd field value.

```
cache[$COL] = $0
```

Otherwise if this is the second time that 2nd field value was seen, it outputs the saved record from when that 2nd field value was first seen and prints the current record below it.

```
else {
    if (fields[$COL] == 2) {print cache[$COL]}
    ...
}
```

The script then outputs all remaining records.

```
    print $0
```